# how to find oracle calculated/computed column list using data dictionary views

Tags: oracle

I would like to find computed column list in oracle database using [Oracle Data Dictionary Views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datadict.htm#i2112).

I would like to add more information. Suppose I have following computed/calculated column in database.

```
ALTER TABLE HR.EMPLOYEES
 ADD FULL_NAME AS ( FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME);
```

I can select this column value in Select Statements.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FULL_NAME FROM HR.EMPLOYEES;
```

Results

> ...
>    174 Ellen Abel
>   ...

I can see this column in TAB_COLUMNS view.

```
 select * from all_tab_columns   C 
 WHERE
 1 = 1
 AND  C.table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'
 AND C.OWNER = 'HR'
 AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FULL_NAME'
 ;
```

I would like to find **given schema, table and column** find that if this column is calculated/computed?

Wrongly I thought that [INDEXES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1061.htm) view gives me this information. But following select returns no rows. This gives only functional indexes.

```
SELECT index_name,index_Type,I.*
FROM ALL_indexes I
WHERE 
1 = 1
AND INDEX_TYPE LIKE 'FUNCTION-BASED%'
AND I.OWNER = 'HR'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column `USER_TAB_COLS.virtual_column = 'YES'` indicates if it's a virtual column.

You can get the expressions for each column with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE data_default IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that there is difference between ALL_TAB_COLS and ALL_TAB_COLUMNS as stated here (https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1123911). ALL_TAB_COLS view differs from "ALL_TAB_COLUMNS" in that hidden columns are not filtered out."